# Why are some objects not showing on the depth pass?

Tags: rendering

I am using blender2.78c to create a visual parking scene model, by using the python script I could produce a RGB picture of the parking scene as well as the depth image.

RGB picture

[image]

And depth image

[image]

My problem is: Why is it rendering only the cars and not the lightposts?

Comment: Why are you using a script for the rendering? Probably there is no light because there is no lamp. Which renderer are you using?

Comment: @HenrikD I guess he refers to the lamps _objects_ that are visible in the first image... they are not visible in the second one the depth map. Now, as to why, it could be needed to see the script that renders it, and perhaps also the .blend file: there could also be clipping, layers, or else...

Comment: forget that with the lamp... I was a little brain AFK, but I still really what to know which renderer he is using otherwise it would be hard to help.

Comment: Without the script is impossible to know what is going on, maybe you disabled renderability, maybe you have the lamps in a different layer. Please use the [edit] link under the question and add more information.